# How to wait for flowable onComplete?

Tags: java, rx-java2

In RxJava2, here is my code:

```java
public void myMethod() {
Flowable.create(e->{
  // do sth.
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<ContentsWithChannelVO>() {
  @Override
  public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) { // do sth. }

  @Override
  public void onNext(ContentsWithChannelVO contentAndChannel) { // do sth. }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable throwable) { // do sth. }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() { // do sth. }
});
doSomething();
}
```

Here is a synchronized problem.

I want to know how to let my method wait for the `flowable` onComplete, that is to say `doSomething()` will be called after the `flowable` onCompleted.

I have searched for it but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) operator, but you need to wrap your method in another observable.

> Concat waits to subscribe to each additional Observable that you pass
>   to it until the previous Observable completes.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to block the consumption of the flow for that (which is generally not recommended):

```java
public void myMethod() {
    Flowable.create(e -> {
       // do sth.
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false)
    .blockingSubscribe(new Subscriber<ContentsWithChannelVO>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) { // do sth. }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ContentsWithChannelVO contentAndChannel) { // do sth. }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) { // do sth. }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() { // do sth. }
    });

    doSomething();
}
```

In this case, having `observeOn` is pointless. Note also you have to use `subscribeOn()` with `false` otherwise the flow livelocks.

If you don't want to execute `doSomething` if the source fails, use `blockingForEach`:

```
public void myMethod() {
    Flowable.create(e -> {
       // do sth.
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false)
    .blockingForEach(contentAndChannel -> { /* do sth. */ });

    doSomething();
}
```